# hibernate postgres many to one mapping issue

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I got the issue with hibernate mapping when generate "create table" sql. **The property sid is String type but it becomes integer type after generating table acl_entry in database.** And i dont know why. This caused the error like:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "acl_entry"
violates foreign key constraint "id"
  Detail: Key (sid)=(0) is not present in table "acl_sid".
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryEx
ecutorImpl.java:2157).
```

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

AclEntry.java:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="aclentry_identifier_seq", sequenceName="aclentry_identifier_seq", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="aclentry_identifier_seq")
@Column(name = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer id;



@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "sid", nullable = false)
@ForeignKey(name = "id")
private AclSid aclSid;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

AclSid.java:

```
@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="aclsid_identifier_seq", sequenceName="aclsid_identifier_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="aclsid_identifier_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer id;



    @Column(name = "sid")
    private String sid;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

My problem is: after the acl_entry generated, its field "sid" is type of integer not the String as expected. This cause to the key(sid) =(0) after generating.

Table acl_entry generated as:

```
mask integer,
  acl_object_identity integer,
  sid integer NOT NULL
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your `@ForeignKey` states that you are referencing the `id` column, not `sid`, which is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "sid", nullable = false)
@ForeignKey(name = "id")
private AclSid aclSid;
```

Try setting

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "sid", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
private AclSid aclSid;
```

`ManyToOne` and `JoinColumn` are JPA annotations.
`ForeignKey` is a Hibernate-specific annotation, and I've personally never used it, so chances are you may not need to either :)

Comment: thanks Zoltán. But my problem is: after the acl_entry generated, its field "sid" is type of integer not the String as expected. This cause to the key(sid) =(0) after generating.